# jQuery/Javascript - Variable into CSS change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I'm writing HTML in Java using a servlet and I'm having a problem where scrolling over a DOM object (third party, jqplot) will light up the text for a particular list. I have HTML (declared before the jQuery):

```
<li id='cap_1'>
  <span>DOG</span>
</li>
```

And the following code later:

```
out.println("<script>$('#chart2').bind('jqplotDataHighlight', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) { var x = 'cap_'+pointIndex; alert(x); $(x).css(\"display\",\"none\"); } );</script>");
```

The alert is triggering and returns correctly (cap_1). But the CSS isn't working (i've tried display, background-color, color, etc - nothing worked).

What am I missing? jQuery and library declarations are confirmed and the bind is part of the jqplot library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `#` symbol before `x`.

`$('#' + x).css(...` and so on

Or, where you declare `x`:

```
... var x = '#cap_' + ...
```

Comment: Bleh - The most simple of things... Thanks for finding!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `'#'` selector:

```
out.println("<script>
               $('#chart2').bind('jqplotDataHighlight', 
                                  function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) { 
                                      var x = '#cap_'+pointIndex; //<-- Here
                                      alert(x); 
                                      $(x).css(\"display\",\"none\"); 
                                  });
            </script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `DOG` selector:

```
out.println("<script>$('#chart2').bind('jqplotDataHighlight', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) { var x = 'li:contains(DOG)'; $(x).css(\"display\",\"none\"); } );</script>");
```